# How can I extract data from one pixel in an image and assign this data to another pixel in another image?

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I extract data from one pixel in an image and assign this data to another pixel in another image?

I have tried several methods and finally used this one and I have got those errors:

1- error: request for member ‘imageData’ in ‘uw’, which is of non-class type ‘IplImage* {aka _IplImage*}’

2- error: request for member ‘widthStep’ in ‘uw’, which is of non-class type ‘IplImage* {aka _IplImage*}’

3- error: ‘class cv::Mat’ has no member named ‘imageData’ ( for the src image part )

4- error: ‘class cv::Mat’ has no member named ‘widthtep’  ( for the src image part )

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
 #define  pi 3.14159265358979323846
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;
 /** @function main */

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
 Mat src;
 src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

 IplImage* uw = cvCreateImage(cvSize(360,(Rmax-Rmin+1)), 8, 3);
  for (double a=0; a<2*pi; a+=step)
  for ( r=Rmin; r<Rmax; r++)
  {

   double iX=(r*cos(a*pi/180))+802;
   double iY=(r*sin(a*pi/180))+612;


    *(uw.imageData + a*uw.widthStep+r*3+0) =
      *(src.imageData + iY*src.widthStep+iX*3+0);

    *(uw.imageData + a*uw.widthStep+r*3+1) =
      *(src.imageData + iY*src.widthStep+iX*3+1);

    *(uw.imageData + a*uw.widthStep+r*3+2) =
      *(src.imageData + iY*src.widthStep+iX*3+2);
  }

  }
```

in addition, when I use a variable (double) cx and cy instead of the numbers 802 and 612, I get an error:

error: ‘cx’ was not declared in this scope

error: ‘cy’ was not declared in this scope

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to access a RGB/BGR pixel in an image is something like this:

```
Mat src, trg;
src = imread( argv[1], 1 );
trg.create(src.size(), src.type());

trg.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);
```

If your image is grayscale (CV_8U), you can also do:

```
trg.at<unsigned char>(y, x) = src.at<unsigned char>(y, x);
```

Comment: i have recievd 2 errors after using this approach.error: ‘tar’ was not declared in this scope , error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

Comment: There was a problem in the trg.create, I used another declaration of a new image  Mat trg(src.size(), src.type()); and it worked. That was helpful, Thanks.